# Intro physic question - Tension

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, string

> A heavy bird sits on a clothesline. Will the tension in the clothesline be affected by the sag in the line? Use parallelograms in your explanation. What are the minimum and maximum tensions possible?

I am having trouble understanding what my professor means by use parallelograms in your explanation, and what the minimum and maximum tensions are possible.

Now I get that increased sag in the line will decrease tension and that decreases in sag will cause an increase in tension. I understand this, but I can't seem to understand the force vector part. I also don't get what he means by minimum and maximum tensions possible.

I have been stuck on this problem for about 30 mins, I checked the text but it has only a paragraph about tension. So any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Increasing sag will *increase* tension.

Comment: @garyp I think by "sag" they mean slack before loading, or a longer line at a given horizontal separation. So more sag would decrease tension.

Comment: @garyp No. Imagine the clothesline is perfectly horizontal with the bird on it. What fraction of the tension is in the vertical direction and thus capable of counteracting the bird's weight?

Comment: @TomB.  Check.  (I never would have interpreted the question that way.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hint:* The tension will be greater for a small sag. That's because large vectors in each side of the rope supporting the bird are needed for a resultant that is equal and opposite to the bird's weight.